# XHR Scrape - Request URL not changing

Tags: r, json, ajax, web-scraping, xmlhttprequest

I have a database of addresses, and I'm trying to scrape the +4 zip code digits from the USPS web app: https://tools.usps.com/zip-code-lookup.htm?byaddress

I'm using Chrome, and the site uses XHR. When I input an address, I'm easily able to find the parameters of my request in the inspector...

[image: Request parameters]

...as well as the data from the response:

[image: Data from response]
(the yellow highlighted data is what I'm trying to scrape)

Every tutorial I've read on this topic says I should now 'just grab the Request URL and paste it in your browser to get the JSON data', and shows a URL that includes all the parameters. Unfortunately in this case, the request URL in the inspector is nearly identical to the browser URL, with none of the search parameters included. Not sure how to proceed, given that.

[image: Request URL as shown in inspector]

Can someone advise as to how I could actually get that JSON table? If it matters, I'm working in R, though I don't necessarily need help with that portion of this problem.

Thanks in advance. Also, new SO user here, so please be kind when pointing out any accidental etiquette breaches in this post.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You [should consider getting around more](https://rud.is/b/2016/02/10/craft-httr-calls-cleverly-with-curlconverter/) w/r/t "tutorial"s.

Answer (score 0):

Poked at robots.txt and terms & faq pages and can't find anything prohibiting scraping. If anyone does, drop a comment and I'll gladly delete the answer.

Sometimes you can't just grab the URL, esp when there's a `POST` request to be made (which is the case here). That's where [`curlconverter`](https://gitlab.com/hrbrmstr/curlconverter) comes in. Right-click on the table entry in the Developer Tools view, select "Copy as cURL" and don't put anything else on the clipboard. Then do:

```
library(curlconverter)

st <- straighten() 
req <- make_req(st)
```

`st` contains a list structure with decomposed request components and `req[[1]]()` is a call-able `httr` function. *However*, if you — immediately — after you run that `make_req()` line move to a new line and use your clipboard's *paste* function, you get the formatted source of said function. In this case, that's:

```
httr::VERB(
  verb = "POST", url = "https://tools.usps.com/tools/app/ziplookup/zipByAddress",
  httr::add_headers(
    `User-Agent` = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:63.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/63.0",
    Accept = "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01",
    `Accept-Language` = "en-US,en;q=0.7,fr-BE;q=0.3",
    Referer = "https://tools.usps.com/zip-code-lookup.htm?byaddress",
    `X-Requested-With` = "XMLHttpRequest",
    DNT = "1", Connection = "keep-alive"
  ),
  httr::set_cookies(
    nsc_usps_com = "MTc0LjYyLjE2Ny45Nw==",
    `NSC_uppmt-xbt8-mc` = "ffffffff3b22378c45525d5f4f58455e445a4a4212d3"
  ),
  body = list(
    companyName = "",
    address1 = "1+Main+Street",
    address2 = "", city = "Cambridge",
    state = "MA", zip = ""
  ),
  encode = "form"
)
```

We can tell from that auto-crafted function that there are cookies to be maintained, JSON to be accepted and — perhaps — some other HTTP header variable to pass, along with `POST` body data.

The next step is to triage what's absolutely needed. I'm not giving hints on how I arrived at what's below since you should do some work. To maintain cookie state, we make an initial `GET` call to the source page to get cookies which will remain intact for as long as the R session is active. Then, we pass in parameters and return the converted JSON:

```
lookup_zip <- function(address_1, address_2 = "", city = "", 
                       state = "", zip = "", company_name = "") {

  suppressPackageStartupMessages({
    require("httr", quietly = TRUE, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
    require("jsonlite", quietly = TRUE, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
  })

  # prime cookies
  httr::GET(
    url = "https://tools.usps.com/zip-code-lookup.htm",
    httr::user_agent("Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:63.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/63.0")
  ) -> res
  httr::stop_for_status(res)

  httr::POST(
    url = "https://tools.usps.com/tools/app/ziplookup/zipByAddress",
    httr::accept_json(),
    httr::user_agent("Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:63.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/63.0"),
    httr::add_headers(
      Referer = "https://tools.usps.com/zip-code-lookup.htm?byaddress",
      `X-Requested-With` = "XMLHttpRequest"
    ),
    body = list(
      companyName = company_name,
      address1 = address_1,
      address2 = address_2, 
      city = city,
      state = state, 
      zip = zip
    ),
    encode = "form"
  ) -> res

  httr::stop_for_status(res)

  out <- httr::content(res, as = "text", encoding = "UTF-8")

  out <- jsonlite::fromJSON(out)

  out

}
```

So, when we run:

```
lookup_zip("1 Main Street", city = "Cambridge", state = "MA")

## $resultStatus
## [1] "SUCCESS"
## 
## $addressList
##                     addressLine1      city state  zip5 zip4 carrierRoute countyName deliveryPoint checkDigit cmar elot
## 1                      1 MAIN ST CAMBRIDGE    MA 02142 1531         C033  MIDDLESEX            99          3    N 0033
## 2                      1 MAIN ST CAMBRIDGE    MA 02142 1531         C033  MIDDLESEX            99          3    N <NA>
## 3                      1 MAIN ST CAMBRIDGE    MA 02142 1500         C033  MIDDLESEX            01          4    N <NA>
## 4               1 MAIN ST STE 14 CAMBRIDGE    MA 02142 1503         C033  MIDDLESEX            01          1    N <NA>
## 5               1 MAIN ST STE 10 CAMBRIDGE    MA 02142 1504         C033  MIDDLESEX            01          0    N <NA>
## 6               1 MAIN ST STE 24 CAMBRIDGE    MA 02142 1506         C033  MIDDLESEX            01          8    N <NA>
## 7                1 MAIN ST STE 6 CAMBRIDGE    MA 02142 1517         C033  MIDDLESEX            99          9    N <NA>
## 8                1 MAIN ST STE 1 CAMBRIDGE    MA 02142 1517         C033  MIDDLESEX            99          9    N <NA>
## 9               1 MAIN ST STE 11 CAMBRIDGE    MA 02142 1517         C033  MIDDLESEX            99          9    N <NA>
## 10              1 MAIN ST STE 13 CAMBRIDGE    MA 02142 1517         C033  MIDDLESEX            99          9    N <NA>
## 11              1 MAIN ST STE 15 CAMBRIDGE    MA 02142 1517         C033  MIDDLESEX            99          9    N <NA>
## 12               1 MAIN ST STE 8 CAMBRIDGE    MA 02142 1524         C033  MIDDLESEX            01          8    N <NA>
## 13   1 MAIN ST STE (Range 2 - 5) CAMBRIDGE    MA 02142 1599         C033  MIDDLESEX          <NA>       <NA>    N <NA>
## 14  1 MAIN ST STE (Range 7 - 10) CAMBRIDGE    MA 02142 1599         C033  MIDDLESEX          <NA>       <NA>    N <NA>
## 15 1 MAIN ST STE (Range 16 - 24) CAMBRIDGE    MA 02142 1599         C033  MIDDLESEX          <NA>       <NA>    N <NA>
## 16              1 MAIN ST STE 12 CAMBRIDGE    MA 02142 1599         C033  MIDDLESEX            99          9    N <NA>
## 17              1 MAIN ST STE 14 CAMBRIDGE    MA 02142 1599         C033  MIDDLESEX            99          9    N <NA>
##    elotIndicator recordType dpvConfirmation defaultFlag               companyName
## 1              A          H               D           Y                      <NA>
## 2           <NA>       <NA>            <NA>        <NA>                      <NA>
## 3           <NA>       <NA>            <NA>        <NA>                      <NA>
## 4           <NA>       <NA>            <NA>        <NA>     BENCHMARKING PARTNERS
## 5           <NA>       <NA>            <NA>        <NA>              C MARKET INC
## 6           <NA>       <NA>            <NA>        <NA> SIMAT HELLIESEN & EICHNER
## 7           <NA>       <NA>            <NA>        <NA>                      <NA>
## 8           <NA>       <NA>            <NA>        <NA>                      <NA>
## 9           <NA>       <NA>            <NA>        <NA>                      <NA>
## 10          <NA>       <NA>            <NA>        <NA>                      <NA>
## 11          <NA>       <NA>            <NA>        <NA>                      <NA>
## 12          <NA>       <NA>            <NA>        <NA>       NEW ENGLAND PENSION
## 13          <NA>       <NA>            <NA>        <NA>                      <NA>
## 14          <NA>       <NA>            <NA>        <NA>                      <NA>
## 15          <NA>       <NA>            <NA>        <NA>                      <NA>
## 16          <NA>       <NA>            <NA>        <NA>                      CEME
## 17          <NA>       <NA>            <NA>        <NA>                      <NA>
```

#### Things you should not do with the above:

- Don't be a jerk #1 : If you're going to make repeated calls, put a delay in (i.e. `Sys.sleep(5)`. You're getting this info for free and my tax $ support the site. You aren't special.
- Don't be a jerk #2 : Cache results, perhaps even on-disk. Re-write the function to use the `memoise` package.
- Don't be a jerk #3 : Don't sell this database you're creating. I'll know if you do (see #4)
- Don't be a jerk #4 : Despite whatever SO claims inherently otherwise w/r/t answers, the above code is AGPL licensed, so you're obligated to release source of any commercial thing you write based on it (if that's your ultimate intent). I have Internet Archive scale systems that crawl the internet daily. I'll know.

It's quite possible this is an innocent academic need, but SO is full of (daily) scraping questions asked by unethical content thieves.